# What would happen if Aromatase turned much of a man`s testosterone levels into estrogen?

Tags: science-based, biology, genetic-engineering

I'd like to create a story in which a genetically modified man has Aromatase Excess syndrome.

For example, if a man has a genetic mutation where he produces a lot of aromatase that turns 10% of his testosterone levels into estrogen (specially estradiol), what would happen to his body?

Consider that the fictitious man in this case has a testosterone level of 500 ng/dl or 5ng/ml and aromatase is turning 10% of his testosterone into estrogens.  A healthy level of estrogen in a young woman is between 80-200 pg/ml of blood, then 10% of 500000pg (500ng) is 50000 picograms or 50nanograms of estrogen.

What would happen if a man had 50000 pg of estradiol, which is many times higher than the average level of estrogen in a woman?

Comment: after some small amount of 'research', I am deleting my previous response.  Not into 'Fantasy'

Answer (score 12):

**These men would become obese and infertile.**

[The Effect of Aromatase on the Reproductive Function of Obese Males.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28679145)

> The expression of aromatase is proportional to body fat mass and
>   causes more fat accumulation, thus forming a vicious cycle. Excessive
>   aromatase activity in adipose tissue leads to increased conversion of
>   androgens into estrogens, eventually results in a reduction of
>   testosterone levels and is the underlying reason for obesity-related
>   infertility.

As aromatase levels rise, an increasing proportion of testosterone is converted into estrogen.  The estrogen causes feedback which tends to suppress testosterone - otherwise estrogen would rise and rise as the body tried to reach normal testosterone levels that the aromatase prevented.

These men would become fat, infertile and have gynecomastia.  Various other metabolic and endocrinology problems would ensue.  This is not especially edgy science fiction.

Comment: [Here is more research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4854098/) in support of Will's answer.  Just enough is good.  Too much is very, very bad.

Comment: I read about Aromatase excess s yndrome in Wikipedia and I saw a photo of a slender child boy who had breasts. They would not necessarily be all obese.

Comment: Children before puberty would not have enough circulating testosterone for the aromatase to act upon.

Comment: So how did a 9 years old boy got breasts?